# Dll consumption in metro apps built using winJs

Tags: javascript, html

Can we consume our own C# dlls in metro style apps which is built using html & win Js?

Answer (score 0):

You can build new C# DLLs as WinRT components and call them from JavaScript. MSDN has a [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755833%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that's relevent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The following post walks you through how to do this with both a C# or C++ external library.

http://blendinsider.com/technical/creating-an-html-metro-style-app-that-references-c-and-c-code-2012-04-13/